# Android application(application class extention) - null object after some time

Tags: android

In my Android application I extend the "Application" class and use it as a singleton. I set in there my "User" object so I can access it from everywhere. For some reason, that object gets null. I have put logs and see that nothing "sets" the object to null.

What I have noticed is that in the logs I print the "Application" object's Id (memory #) and when the user object gets null, the "Application" object has changed id (new instance for some reason?). But the rest of the stuff in the "Application" object are fine, only user has a problem.

Any ideas what could cause this? I guess out of memory or something? Any ideas on how to overcome this without having to do major changes (like adding an sqlite?)

Comment: where is your code and logcat??

Answer (score 1):

It is commont in android, you have to check it for null values and load them again.

Comment: @Panos how much data are you using on that class? if you follow the Android lifecycle, you can just use the `onCreate` and `onDestroy` methods to populate whatever information you use, and keep a file (such as a `SharedPrefference` to hold those values...

Comment: @Bonatti It is just a classic "user" object with like 10 fields. It's not that much. I tried to sarialize it in a json and save it every time the setter is called and then if the getter is null to retrieve it again, but for some reason it does not work always... I will try with sugarOrm probably tonight

Comment: Then, like my previous comment, I highly suggest the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) It is a very fast xml object edittor that allows you to save native variables, and will block code until it has been successfully serialized/unserialized... I use it a lot, and find it the best way to move data through severa lapplications (while still being the best object in a single application to use small storage) [this link will also help](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: I often use _gson_, it is very fast to serialize anything to _SharedPreferences_. It is slow in performance for bigger data, so you can also cache your requests, if it is possible. If you want better performance you can use parcelable or database, but it takes more time to implement.

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas what could cause this?

Most likely your object was not used or linked, so the Android OS targetted it as disposable, and the garbage collector freed its memory allocation

> Any ideas on how to overcome this without having to do major changes (like adding an sqlite?)

Without seeing your code, it may be hard to help, however keep the following guidelines:

1 - Keep a direct link to the resources you are currently using (so, adding a attribute that links to your original object is fine

```
Boolean isFatherObjectAlive = "Original Object"."flag";
```

2 - Keep a command executing or an instruction that makes direct usage of the singleton object

```
singletonObject.doSomething();
```